# Adding New list to SharePoint , will be added to power bi dynamically, just like getdata in excel from folder

Tags: list, sharepoint, powerbi

I'm trying to find a way to add a list from template in sharepoint and at the same time when i add this list it will be automatically added in power bi as a table..
just like when i tried to do that with excel, i get all data from folder that has couple of excel sheet with the same structure.. is that possible in power bi ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to transform your SharePoint List data into a Power BI report?

Here are steps:

1.Open Power BI Desktop ->Get data ->More.

2.Online Services->SharePoint Online List->connect

3.Paste the address into the Site URL field in the open dialog box-> sign in to Microsoft 365.

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-sharepoint-online-list